# Ldap search for objects where attribute X contains multiple values

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I would like to know if it is possible to do a search like this:
"give me all objects where description has more than 1 value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. At least not from a single LDAP Query without somehow parsing the results.

I know of a [tool that will provide those results](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/DuplicateAttributeValueLocaterTool) however it has not been updated in a while but last time I used it, it worked.